# SSRS: Summing Group totals

Tags: reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

I have 3 groups. in group 3 I have the following calculation:
=IIF(SUM(Fields!ViolationPoints.Value * Fields!TimeWeight.Value) > 30, 30, SUM(Fields!ViolationPoints.Value * Fields!TimeWeight.Value))

How can I then sum these totals in a group 1 field. Basically I get about 2 or 3 records in gorup 3 and I need to show the sum of that in gorup 1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need more information; are you using a Table to display your groups or are these simply calculations that you want to perform outside of the Tables?

Comment: This is a table with 3 groups. The calculation is in group 3 and I want to sum up the group 3 calcs in the group 1 header.